# Авто инкремент ключей в HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Подскажите, почему не работает код.
В Map необходимо добавлять имя объекта с уникальным ключом.

```
class Mamam {
    static HashMap<Integer, String> names = new HashMap<>();
}

class Customer {
    Customer(String name) {
        int x = 0;
        if (Mamam.names.containsKey(x)){
            Mamam.names.put(x++,name);
        } else {
            Mamam.names.put(x,name);
        }
    }
}

public class Res {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer asd = new Customer("Ivan");
        Customer asd2 = new Customer("Petr");
        Customer asd3 = new Customer("Vasya");
        Customer asd4 = new Customer("Ilya");
        Customer asd5 = new Customer("Vasya2");
        Customer asd6 = new Customer("Oleg");
        System.out.print(Mamam.names);
        System.out.println(Mamam.names.size());
    }
}
```

Вывод:

> {0=Oleg}
>
> 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам уже ответили почему, прямо когда я уже подготовил свой пример кода, Вам уже показали как использовать статическую переменную, я сделал слегка иначе:

```
class Customer {
    Customer(String name) {
        int x = 0;
        while(Mamam.names.containsKey(x)){
            x++;
        }
        Mamam.names.put(x,name);
    }
}
```

Вот код целиком:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

class Mamam {
    static HashMap<Integer, String> names = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
}

class Customer {
    Customer(String name) {
        int x = 0;
        while(Mamam.names.containsKey(x)){
            x++;
        }
        Mamam.names.put(x,name);
    }
}

public class Res {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Customer("Ivan");
        new Customer("Petr");
        new Customer("Vasya");
        new Customer("Ilya");
        new Customer("Vasya2");
        new Customer("Oleg");
        System.out.println(Mamam.names);
        System.out.println(Mamam.names.size());
    }
}
```

Однако помимо корректности в Вашем коде есть ряд архитектурных ошибок

1. Выбор ключа - зона ответсвенности хранилища, иначе вы можете нарушить логику генерации ключей извне(по месту добавления данных в мапу), в моем варианте это не получится сделать, т.к. эта логика инкапсулированиа в метод `Mamam.add()`:
2. Вы добавляете данные в мапу из конструктора кастомера, это однако зона ответственности управляющего кода, кастомер не должен знать куда его кладут.
3. Вы напрямую обращаетесь к статическому полю name - это тоже нарушение инкапсуляции

---

```
class Mamam {

    private static HashMap<Integer, String> names = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    public static void add(Customer c) {
        int x = 0;
        while(names.containsKey(x)){
            x++;
        }
        Mamam.names.put(x, c.name);
    }

    public static void stats() {
        System.out.println(names);
        System.out.println(names.size());
    }
}

class Customer {
    String name;
    Customer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Res {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mamam.add(new Customer("Ivan"));
        Mamam.add(new Customer("Petr"));
        Mamam.add(new Customer("Vasya"));
        Mamam.add(new Customer("Ilya"));
        Mamam.add(new Customer("Vasya2"));
        Mamam.add(new Customer("Oleg"));
        Mamam.stats();
    }
}
```

Вот вывод

> {0=Ivan, 1=Petr, 2=Vasya, 3=Ilya, 4=Vasya2, 5=Oleg}
>
> 6

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает

Comment: @DannyMayers почитайте дополнение

Comment: Но метод add не срабатывает автоматом, на него же нужно послать объект?
Я запустил код, но мапа пустая.
Как в конструктор Customer засунуть этот метод?

Comment: @DannyMayers еще раз обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Принял! Работает

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что при создании нового объекта класса Customer переменная x, создавалась заново, поэтому, диапазон был, либо 0 либо 1. НО, в этом вызове:

```
Mamam.names.put(x++,name);
```

x++ инкрементация проводилась после вызова метода. Поэтому в функцию посылалась просто x. В итоге все записи были на ключ 0.

При таком синтаксисе ++x происходит сначала инкрементация, а потом отправление в функцию, а при таком x++ сначала вызывается функция , а потом происходит инкрементация.

```js
import java.util.*;
class Mamam {
    static HashMap<Integer, String> names = new HashMap<>();
  
}

class Customer {

public static int x = 0;
    Customer(String name) {

        if(Mamam.names.containsKey(x)){
        
            Mamam.names.put(++x,name);
        }else{
            Mamam.names.put(x,name);
        }

    }

}



public class test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Customer asd = new Customer("Ivan");
        Customer asd2 = new Customer("Petr");
        Customer asd3 = new Customer("Vasya");
        Customer asd4 = new Customer("Ilya");
        Customer asd5 = new Customer("Vasya2");
        Customer asd6 = new Customer("Oleg");
        System.out.print(Mamam.names);
        System.out.println(Mamam.names.size());




    }
    }
```

Comment: У Вас код слегка избыточен, однако все верно и Вы первый ответили, за это +

Comment: Спасибо, большое!